# Android Debugging after app removed?

Tags: android

I am attempting to debug a service that is supposed to run even after the user closes and then removes the app. I want to debug `onTaskRemoved` which gets called when the user presses their phone's history button and clears it out. But when I start debug mode, it disconnects when I get rid of the app:

`Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'`

Is there a way to continue debugging after the user clears out the app? Or is there a special way to debug a service?

This is probably irrelevant but just for an idea of my service

```
@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    context = getApplicationContext();
    Intent restartService = new Intent(context, this.getClass());
    restartService.setPackage(getPackageName());
    PendingIntent restartServicePI = PendingIntent.getService(context, 1, restartService, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
// Restart once killed by android or user
AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmService.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 100, restartServicePI);
// ^Try setRepeating
Toast.makeText(context, "onTaskRemoved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: You can not debug after clearing your app.

Comment: make sure you don't have `ServiceInfo.FLAG_STOP_WITH_TASK` set, that will just stop the service without the callback you want being called. Also make sure you put log statements in these methods to make sure if they are getting called or not. (I've found logcat statements as useful for services debugging as 'debugger')

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use

```
adb shell dumpsys alarm | grep com.my.package
```

or something like this.

Comment: I might not be using this correctly but I just typed that into the shell and started debugging and it didn't trip over the breakpoint while the toast showed. It said "Disconnected".

Comment: What does `dumpsys alarm` do? Thanks!

Comment: It only shows planned alarms. It's not for debugging. Maybe other dumpsys will show more info about service but I think it's also removed with app.